# Dynamically add current user name in Chef file resource

Tags: chef-infra, recipe

I have the following `chef` recipe to write some data to a file in the `current` user's home directory. As you can see, `vagrant` user is hardcoded in my case. What do I have to do so that the code gets the `user` dynamically based on who is currently logged in?

```
file '/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa' do
  content "This is the super secret"
  mode '0755'
  owner 'vagrant'
  group 'vagrant'
end
```

I tried doing something like the following but it does not work:

`file '/home/#{node['user']}/.ssh/id_rsa'`

Comment: If you're talking about who's running the `chef-client` command, then remove the owner and group and let the system do. If not (chef running as root in crontab or as service), this makes no real sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In almost all cases `chef-client` or `chef-solo` is being run as root, either as a system service or via `sudo`. If this is for setting up a test environment in Test Kitchen, just hardcode. If this is for workstation set up then then you can find the username in `ENV['USER']`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested.
Single quoting prevents variable from being evaluated. This should work:

```
file "/home/#{node['user']}/.ssh/id_rsa"
```